# Mount a remote folder on Nautilus... where is the mount point?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

When I use Nautilus to perform a mount on a volume, where is the mount point located in the local filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out $HOME/.gvfs - mount name will differ per host - this also assumes you connected it as a user mount.